# Costs in a game

Tags: modeling

I am trying to find the best model to solve the following problem:

I have various players in a network. I have to visit all these players in the network. The players are visited in an optimal route, and to visit all the players I have costs (km and hours). Some of these players have time restrictions: that means I can only visit these players within specific time windows, for example between 16:00 and 17:00. The route to visit all the players is influenced by this player.

I want to know: what are the extra costs I have to make because of this restriction?

An option is to calculate the costs of the whole network with these players and the costs of the network without these players. But it could be that in the same region (or street) there is another player with the same time window. So in this case they would split the extra costs of this restriction.

So If I have 3 players with time restrictions, I would have the following costs:

costs(the 3 players with their time restricitions are present) =

costs(only player 1 and 2 have the time restriction, player 3 not) =

costs(only player 2 and 3 have the time restriction, player 1 not) =

costs(only player 1 and 3 have the time restriction, player 2 not) =

costs(only player 1 has the time restriction) =

costs(only player 2 has the time restriction) =

costs(only player 3 has the time restriction) =

costs(none of the players have the time restriction) =

These costs can be calculated. But the question is: what is now the costs of a specific time restriction of a player?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the specific time restrictions - if they overlap or are very far apart.

For example, the cost for when exactly one player has time restrictions, is the same as where none of them have time restrictions - you simply manage your route in the same way, only start at a specific time that will fit in the restricted time window.

The problem is when you have two players that are relatively near, but their time windows is far appart (e.g. one in the morning, one in the evening). In this case, you have to visit that place twice, which will increase your cost.

Your problem is a classic [Traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). The problem itself is NP-hard with a brutal time complexity of $O(n^2 2^n)$. In other words: it will be *really* hard to solve the problem even when $n$ gets a little high (say ~10).

So most of the times you will be working with non-exact (i.e. non-optimal) solutions, which will make it almost impossible to calculate your cost difference.